# PhpStorm (WebStorm) - Constant with HTML code inside backtick in a typescript file becomes plain text after 4120 characters. Loses syntax highlighting

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, constants, webstorm

I am using PhpStorm (WebStorm) to build an angular 2 app using typescript. I have a .ts file that exports a constant that has the HTML (the view) of the component.

PhpStorm (WebStorm) has this cool feature that recognizes HTML Syntax, error highlighting and coding assistance within backticks (`). The issue that I am facing is that after 4120 characters, the HTML syntax recognition stops and the code becomes plain text.

I have searched around but haven't found anything on it. Is this a bug? Maybe there's a setting for it?

**4120** characters with HTML syntax working:
[image]

**4121** characters with HTML syntax NOT working:
[image]

**PhpStorm Version:**
PhpStorm 2016.1
Build #PS-145.258, built on March 16, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_40-release-b132 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see anything in the [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues). I can reproduce it for the HTML language injection (occurs in PHP and JS as well). When I try a different language injection (e.g. SQL in php files), there did not appear to be a limit.

You can create a new language injection rule by going to **Setting** > **Editor** > **Language Injections**. Click the green plus sign button. Provide at minimum the following. Refer to the links at the bottom if you want to tweak it further:

**Name:** *(choose a name)*
**ID:** HTML
**Places Patterns:**

```
+ jsLiteralExpression().withText(string().matchesBrics("(\\<\\<\\<)?.*\\</?<anyname>.*>.*"))
```

Two other quick fixes that are good to know about:

- Languages can be defined in the comments. Add the following to the beginning of your file: `/* language=HTML */`
- Languages can be injected temporarily. With the caret in the string, press `Alt` + `Enter` and select **Inject language or reference**. Then select **HTML**.

#### References

- [IntelliLang Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/intellilang.html)
- [Language Injections Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/language-injections.html)
- [IntelliLang Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1105?pr=phpStorm)